# Need care for filter order?

Tags: elasticsearch

There are a lot of articles to talk about `filter order` of `es` on the internet.But a lot of them are out of date.

I want to know in `es` after version `2.+`,i need to care of the filter order?

Such as,There are 1000000 docs which `field1` equals `value1`,and there are just 100 docs which `field2` equals `value2`.

1.

```
  { "bool": {
        "filter": [
           { "term": { "field1": "value1" }}, 
           { "term": { "field2": "value2" }}
        ]
  }}
```

2.

```
  { "bool": {
        "filter": [
           { "term": { "field2": "value2" }}, 
           { "term": { "field1": "value1" }}
        ]
  }}
```

There are difference of `dsl1` and `dsl2`?

Comment: i once asked the same question to ES support people.They told me not to worry about order as ES will execute the query in most optimized way, this is like 2 years ago.

Comment: @user3775217,Some articles tell me not to worry,but others opposite.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727193/elasticsearch-order-of-filters-for-best-performance

Comment: if filters are boolean based(bitset based), then i guess they don't matter if you have them in filtered part of query.As each document is evaluated for each bool based fitler and then each filter bool is combined to match the document. Simillarly caching boolean based filters make sense, as they are independent of each other