# Execution plan of es search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use `Elasticsearch 5`'s `profile` api to find the search execution plan.

Here are my two different querys:

1:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "field1": "f1"
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "field3": {
                        "gt": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "field1": "f1"
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "field3": {
                        "gt": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The difference between the two queries is just that `query1` uses `should` and `query2` use `filter`.

But the `children` `profile` results of two queries are the same.

Such as:

```
"children": [
{
    "type": "BooleanQuery",
    "description": "field1:f1 field3:[2 TO 9223372036854775807]",
    "time": "0.06531500000ms",
    "breakdown": {
        "score": 0,
        "build_scorer_count": 0,
        "match_count": 0,
        "create_weight": 65314,
        "next_doc": 0,
        "match": 0,
        "create_weight_count": 1,
        "next_doc_count": 0,
        "score_count": 0,
        "build_scorer": 0,
        "advance": 0,
        "advance_count": 0
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "TermQuery",
            "description": "field1:f1",
            "time": "0.05287500000ms",
            "breakdown": {
                "score": 0,
                "build_scorer_count": 0,
                "match_count": 0,
                "create_weight": 52874,
                "next_doc": 0,
                "match": 0,
                "create_weight_count": 1,
                "next_doc_count": 0,
                "score_count": 0,
                "build_scorer": 0,
                "advance": 0,
                "advance_count": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "",
            "description": "field3:[2 TO 9223372036854775807]",
            "time": "0.001556000000ms",
            "breakdown": {
                "score": 0,
                "build_scorer_count": 0,
                "match_count": 0,
                "create_weight": 1555,
                "next_doc": 0,
                "match": 0,
                "create_weight_count": 1,
                "next_doc_count": 0,
                "score_count": 0,
                "build_scorer": 0,
                "advance": 0,
                "advance_count": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

Does `ElasticSearch` create multiple threads, then each thread executes one `filter` item and then the results are merged in the end?

But in my mind,i think `es` will use a `filter pipeline`,execute `filter` items one by one.Such as [elasticsearch-order-of-filters-for-best-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727193/elasticsearch-order-of-filters-for-best-performance) says

> In case 1, the execution will be slower because all documents from the past month will need to go through filter A first, which is not cached.
>
> In case 2, you first filter out all the documents without the type XYZ, which is fast because filter B is cached. Then the documents that made it through filter B can go through filter A. So even though filter A is not cached, the execution will still be faster since there are mush less documents left in the filter pipeline.

How es to execute multiple filter item?