# Is it possible to affect execution order of filters in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

We have a query of the form:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "userId": {
                            "value": "a_user_id",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "date": {
                            "from": 1648598400000,
                            "to": 1648684799999,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*MyQuery*",
                        "fields": [
                            "aField^1.0",
                            "anotherField^1.0",
                            "thirdField^1.0"
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

If we remove the third filter (the `query_string` one), performance is dramatically improved (typically going from around 2000 to 20 ms) for different variants of the above query.

The thing is, the first two filters (on `userId` and the `date` range) will always result in only a handful of search hits (say 50 or so).

So, if it was possible to hint that to Elasticsearch, or otherwise affect the query plan, it could solve our issue.

In old (1.x) versions of ES it seems that this was affected by the order of filters. from [Elasticsearch: Order of filters for best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727193/elasticsearch-order-of-filters-for-best-performance):

> "The order of filters in a bool clause is important for performance. More-specific filters should be placed before less-specific filters in order to exclude as many documents as possible, as early as possible. If Clause A could match 10 million documents, and Clause B could match only 100 documents, then Clause B should be placed before Clause A."

But newer versions are smarter - https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order:

> Q: Does the order in which I put my queries/filters in the query DSL matter?
> A: No, because they will be automatically reordered anyway based on their respective costs and match costs.

But is it still possible to reach the desired outcome here by modifying the ES search request somehow?

Comment: are you using the * wildcard operator in the query_string clause?

Comment: Your query performance is decreasing while adding `query_string` because you are passing wildcard query which is starting with `*`.  You can read same in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) documentation where they have mentioned that `
Avoid beginning patterns with * or ?. This can increase the iterations needed to find matching terms and slow search performance.`

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below, so that filters run first and will only select ~50 or so documents and then your costly `query_string` (because of the leading wildcard) will only run on those 50 docs.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*MyQuery*",
            "fields": [
              "aField^1.0",
              "anotherField^1.0",
              "thirdField^1.0"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "userId": {
              "value": "a_user_id",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "from": 1648598400000,
              "to": 1648684799999,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```